# Generate a saturation/brightness mask using gradients

Tags: css, gradient, mask, color-picker, hsl

I would like to know if it's possible to generate a mask of saturation+brightness that are used in color pickers for instance (something like http://johndyer.name/lab/colorpicker/refresh_web/colorpicker/images/map-hue.png) but using only linear-gradient in css3 ?
I tried severals things, such as :

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, hsla(0,100%,0,0) 0%, hsla(0,0%,0%,.5) 100%), /* saturation mask */
            linear-gradient(to top, hsla(0,0%,0%,.5) 0%, hsla(0,0%,100%,.5) 100%), /* lightness mask */
```

but I can't make something like the picture, can't find the right combinaison, and because I don't fully understand, I don't know if it's possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is maybe the way you write it.

1. for the image, 1 gradient + a background-color will do.
2. you did not close correctly you rules , one value is still expected `100%)` **`,`** `/* li`
   :)
3. this could be it :

```
ele {
background: 
    linear-gradient(0deg, hsla(0,0%,0%,.5) 0%, hsla(0,0%,100%,.5) 100%) no-repeat left ,
    white   linear-gradient(180deg, hsla(0,0%,0%,.5) 0%, hsla(0,0%,100%,.5) 100%) no-repeat right;
    background-size:95% 100%, 5% 100%;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ubDsr (gradient covers body)

Answer (score 0):

You had your gradients reversed and some incorrect hsla values.
Just use hex notation, it's easier in this case:

```
background-image:
  linear-gradient(to top, #000 0%, transparent 100%),   /* lightness*/
  linear-gradient(to right, #fff 0%, transparent 100%); /* saturation */
```

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jg65ftcz/) where you can compare the result with an image-based solution  (normal = gradients, hover = Bootstrap Colorpicker).